# Can someone put you in jail if you are only 13 and you were chatting online?

Tags: social-engineering

I was chatting online with a guy. First, he was being nice, but later he became mean. He said that he would put me in jail for going on a site. I did not break the law or did anything, just chat, a small talk.

He wanted me to cam, and I said no. He said that if I didn't cam with him, he would hack and put me in jail. I said "I am a kid, please don't, sorry". I told my mom and she said that he might be joking and stuff.

I was worried and I am still worried. Help me please!

Comment: From what I'm hearing, this guy would be classified as a [predator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Online_predator). When people do stuff like that, just walk away (and tell your parents). They can't put you in jail.

Comment: If you didn't tell/show/display any of your personal info (including your display name), then he shouldn't have any *real-life* info about you, thus he couldn't do anything. Keep calm, and ignore him.

Comment: Probably he was trying to take advantage over you. This is why social networking sites put age restrictions.

Comment: He is lying, he can't hack you. Show this to your parents.

Comment: Listen, predators have done this since well before the internet.  For example they molest a child and then warn the victim not to tell anyone or he or she (the victim) will get in trouble.  I'll say with some confidence it was a grown man and that while he had you on cam he would manipulate you -- if he was able -- into getting undressed or whatever, all with the threat of you getting in trouble otherwise.  Bottom line, you are not going to go to jail.  100%.  But the guy you were talking to probably should if he had succeeded with you.  Tell your parents immediately.

Comment: Hi Lilly - this is actually off topic here, but the guidance you have been given so far is good. Parents or law enforcement should be the preferred next steps.

Comment: If he could hack you he'd already have done it. It's an empty threat. But even if it weren't, if he did hack you he'd be committing a felony crime. In point of fact, just by threatening and harassing you, he's broken some serious laws already. But you haven't. So, if I were you, I wouldn't be worried. But he should be. Don't say anything else to him, discuss it with your parents and contact law enforcement. Chances are if he's doing this to you, he's doing it to other people.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if trolling or not. Unfortunately, if it isn't, I don't have the space to say what I want to say as a comment so meh. I'm answering then 'flagging'.

As you might have noticed, there are horrible people on the internet. Some of them use their skills for evil, not good. And some of them decide to use "social engineering" that way. In this case

1. He's attempting to use your age
2. And supposed inexperience
3. To make you do something that might compromise you. And he'd use that as a way to make you do more things you don't want to do.

I'd suggest simply walking away. Report it to an admin if possible and just leave that site if no action is taken. No one can put you in jail for 'going to a site'. However, if stuff like this happens on a site, its clearly not a safe place for people of any age.

Comment: I'd add to seriously consider leaving the site even if action *is* taken. Some sites are just inherently nasty.

Answer (score 2):

First thing is to talk to your parents about this.

Second :

- nobody can "hack" you just by going to a site using an up to date OS and browser. They could try more social engineering to trick you into executing a malicious file, but unless that happened, you're safe. The worst they can do is a denial of service attack against your Internet connection but it isn't anything to be worried about, a call to your ISP is sufficient to solve the issue. Theoretically, zero-day exploits can be used but in practice, teenage scum doesn't have the resources to buy or find zero-days.
- don't give out any information that could be used to identify you or figure out where you live, this includes school's or teacher's name, real-life friend's names or their online handles (Facebook, Twitter, etc). It should be impossible for anyone to link your online pseudonymous identity to your real life identity. That way, if something goes wrong you should be able to just create a new online identity and start over.
- avoid going to nasty sites where this kind of lowlife resides. Gaming communities are definitely not safe, nor any kind of "hacker" or "underground" forums.